# Installing psyco for python on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, psyco

I'm having some trouble installing psyco on my Macbook pro running Snow Leopard with python 2.6.1.

I've been trying to force python to run in 32-bit mode using the command

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

Further, I have tried the Macport py26-psyco, which seems to finish but the module cannot be found when compiling.

> $ sudo python setup.py install
>   PROCESSOR = 'ivm'
>   running install
>   running build
>   running build_py
>   running build_ext
>   building 'psyco._psyco' extension
>   gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -DALL_STATIC=1 -Ic/ivm -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c c/psyco.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/c/psyco.o
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:48,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/psyfunc.c: In function ‘psycofunction_call’:
>   c/psyfunc.c:801: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:49,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_reset’:
>   c/stats.c:260: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_dump’:
>   c/stats.c:298: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_top’:
>   c/stats.c:326: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:75,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c: In function ‘PsycoMember_GetOne’:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c:16: warning: unused variable ‘w2’
>   c/psyco.c: At top level:
>   c/codegen.c:748: warning: ‘integer_lshift’ defined but not used
>   c/ivm/prolog/insns-igen.i:175: warning: ‘psyco_insn_assertdepth’ defined but not used
>   c/ivm/prolog/insns-igen.i:197: warning: ‘psyco_insn_dynamicfreq’ defined but not used
>   c/codegen.c:66: warning: ‘cc_from_vsource’ defined but not used
>   c/Objects/plongobject.c:20: warning: ‘PsycoLong_AsDouble’ defined but not used
>   c/Objects/plistobject.c:116: warning: ‘PsycoList_SingletonNew’ defined but not used
>   c/codegen.c: In function ‘psyco_generic_call’:
>   c/codegen.c:423: warning: ‘_arg’ may be used uninitialized in this function
>   /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
>   Installed assemblers are:
>   /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
>   /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:48,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/psyfunc.c: In function ‘psycofunction_call’:
>   c/psyfunc.c:801: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:49,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_reset’:
>   c/stats.c:260: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_dump’:
>   c/stats.c:298: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_top’:
>   c/stats.c:326: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:75,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c: In function ‘PsycoMember_GetOne’:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c:16: warning: unused variable ‘w2’
>   c/psyco.c: At top level:
>   c/codegen.c:748: warning: ‘integer_lshift’ defined but not used
>   c/ivm/prolog/insns-igen.i:175: warning: ‘psyco_insn_assertdepth’ defined but not used
>   c/ivm/prolog/insns-igen.i:197: warning: ‘psyco_insn_dynamicfreq’ defined but not used
>   c/codegen.c:66: warning: ‘cc_from_vsource’ defined but not used
>   c/Objects/plongobject.c:20: warning: ‘PsycoLong_AsDouble’ defined but not used
>   c/Objects/plistobject.c:116: warning: ‘PsycoList_SingletonNew’ defined but not used
>   c/codegen.c: In function ‘psyco_generic_call’:
>   c/codegen.c:423: warning: ‘_arg’ may be used uninitialized in this function
>   c/psyco.c: At top level:
>   c/psyco.c:1064: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
>   compilation terminated.
>   In file included from c/psyco.c:1:
>   c/psyco.h:13:3: error: #error "64-bit systems not supported at all.  See help on psyco.sf.net"
>   In file included from c/dispatcher.h:10,
>                    from c/codemanager.h:10,
>                    from c/psyco.c:3:
>   c/vcompiler.h: In function ‘PsycoObject_New’:
>   c/vcompiler.h:743: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
>   c/vcompiler.h: In function ‘PsycoObject_Resize’:
>   c/vcompiler.h:757: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
>   In file included from c/dispatcher.h:12,
>                    from c/codemanager.h:10,
>                    from c/psyco.c:3:
>   c/codegen.h:15:3: error: #error "-----------------------------------------------------"
>   c/codegen.h:16:3: error: #error "Sorry, non-32-bit platforms are not supported at all."
>   c/codegen.h:17:3: error: #error "You may try with a Python compiled in 32-bit         "
>   c/codegen.h:18:3: error: #error "compatibility mode.  Note that Psyco will probably   "
>   c/codegen.h:19:3: error: #error "never support non-32-bit platforms, as it is no      "
>   c/codegen.h:20:3: error: #error "longer actively developed.  Instead, the PyPy group  "
>   c/codegen.h:21:3: error: #error "plans to replace it with a more flexible and easily  "
>   c/codegen.h:22:3: error: #error "retargettable Psyco-for-PyPy during the year 2006.   "
>   c/codegen.h:23:3: error: #error "See http://codespeak.net/pypy/                       "
>   c/codegen.h:24:3: error: #error "-----------------------------------------------------"
>   In file included from c/ivm/iinitialize.h:12,
>                    from c/initialize.h:42,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/ivm/idispatcher.c: In function ‘psyco_unify’:
>   c/ivm/idispatcher.c:202: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:46,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/dispatcher.c: In function ‘fz_internal_copy’:
>   c/dispatcher.c:131: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
>   c/dispatcher.c: In function ‘fz_compress’:
>   c/dispatcher.c:233: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
>   c/dispatcher.c:239: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:48,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/psyfunc.c: In function ‘psycofunction_call’:
>   c/psyfunc.c:801: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:49,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_reset’:
>   c/stats.c:260: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_dump’:
>   c/stats.c:298: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   c/stats.c: In function ‘psyco_stats_top’:
>   c/stats.c:326: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyDict_Next’ from incompatible pointer type
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:53,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/codemanager.c: In function ‘psyco_shrink_code_buffer’:
>   c/codemanager.c:235: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long int’
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:60,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/Objects/pobject.c: In function ‘getdictoffset’:
>   c/Objects/pobject.c:257: error: ‘SIZE_OF_LONG_BITS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   c/Objects/pobject.c:257: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   c/Objects/pobject.c:257: error: for each function it appears in.)
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:61,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/Objects/pabstract.c:723:3: error: #error "omitted code from Python 2.3 here"
>   In file included from c/initialize.h:75,
>                    from c/psyco.c:14:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c: In function ‘PsycoMember_GetOne’:
>   c/Objects/pstructmember.c:16: warning: unused variable ‘w2’
>   lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccjHgyCU.out (No such file or directory)
>   error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this before compiling:
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"
then in the setup.py

replace
extra_link_args = [ ]
with
extra_link_args = [ **'-L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib'** ]

then just run:
python setup.py install

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on my MacBook Pro using OS X 10.7.

I was able to compile it using "sudo python2.5 setup.py install"

Not it work's like charm. Hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question, but as an alternative, did you try installing from the source, as detailed [here](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/psycoguide/sources.html) and [here?](http://codespeak.net/svn/psyco/dist/README.txt)

Furthermore, you can force 32bit python as well by invoking the command `python2.6-32` in the terminal, which may be a bit more convenient for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Why compile things on your own when [there is an easy way out](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/psyco/)?

1. Install [ActivePython 2.6 for Mac](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads)
2. Open Terminal and type `pypm install psyco`